# Using jQuery selectors to get form elements based on value or state

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Is it possible to us jQuery to select a collection of form elements based on their value and/or state?

For instance, I have some code that looks like

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(element){
    if(this.checked)
    {
         //do something with the checked checkeboxes
    }
});
```

I'd like to remove the interior conditional, and somehow add it to the initial selection.  Either as part of the selector string, or via some additional method call on the chain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specifically for the `checked` attribute, you can use the [:checked](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked) selector:

```
var checkedInputs = $('input:checked');
```

For other attributes, you can use the [attribute filters](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 1):

Also for arbitrary filtering, use `filter` (as @CMS suggests). It's like `grep` but specifically for jQuery selection sets.

```
jQuery("input[type='checkbox']")
    .filter(function(){ return this.checked; })
    .each(function() {
        // Do something with "this"
    });
```